# Error in the fresh symfony installation

Tags: php, symfony

I do this simple things:

1. `symfony new sample` (Symfony 2.7.5 at now)
2. `cd sample`
3. `./app/console server:run` (Server runs on localhost:8000)

Fresh installation has some placeholder Bundle which defines `/` route. So I go to `localhost:8000/` and I got this error:

```
ContextErrorException in AbstractToken.php line 70:
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class __PHP_Incomplete_Class could not be converted to string
```

In the `Profiler` when he runs `SecurityDataCollector::collect()` and collector tries to execute `AbstractToken::getUsername()`

What's wrong with clear symfony installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. I have cookie from another symfony's server on `localhost:8000`. Just clear up cookies and all starts working